# Get all of the videos and activities from a Youtube user

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm trying to get all of the videos uploaded by a Youtube user, the `Uri` I used is this one : `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/uploads`, which I've got from this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds).

The same goes with the user activities it seems I can't get all of the user activities using the Uri described in the same website.

So anyone has any idea how to get all of the user's uploads and activities?

Comment: Show what you have tried. Explain what is not working.

Comment: Well it's not a matter of if it is working or not. Because it's working, but the xml I'm receiving contains only a few entries, for example for he videos it contains 12 entries, while the user has uploaded more than that.

Comment: The problem I'm having is with the url, I can't find the correct one to use

Comment: Strange to get 12 entries as the default should be 25 per request. Maybe you used a max-results parameter? Note that there might be a link inside the response for the next page. Note that you are using version 2 which is deprecated. There is also a version 3.

Comment: No I didn't use max resault. More like I tried to used to get more videos but it didn't seem to work. As for the next page link I couldn't find any.

Comment: You want the uploaded videos feed of user "userID" ? When i try the link given, i see in the response: <openSearch:totalResults>18</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage> As you can see the default is 25 results as maximum per request. Since this user "UserID" has only 18 videos (less than 25), all 18 entries should be returned in 1 request and then there will be no next page link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 7 (in words: seven) samples of how to get the uploaded videos with the new awesome v3 Api here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/
It should be easy to look at one and convert it into the language of your desire. 
With this tool you can test all the variations of input to find out how to get all videos:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#try-it
(Spoiler: Default settings)
You can get the PlaylistID that contains all uploads by fetching the channel Informations:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it

I recommend that you take a look at the V3 API and good luck!